deflationary tokens vs inflationary tokens

Why do deflationary tokens exist?
What are the advantages?
How they are different from inflationary tokens?


Deflationary tokens exist primarily to create scarcity and incentivize holders. By reducing the token supply over time, these tokens aim to increase their value over the long term. In other words, this scarcity can drive demand and, in turn, support the token's price.
On the other hand, inflationary tokens have an increasing supply and may face downward pressure on value as the supply expands. To wrap it up, deflationary tokens incentivize holding and scarcity, while inflationary tokens may encourage spending or investment in projects that can offset the dilution caused by new token issuance.
